# Fails Conecting Outlook Add-In to Exchange 2013 WS

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to establish a connection with Exchange 2013 to retrieve a list of Contacts (from Global Contacts) given a certain criteria. This code works from a test console application, but when I place it in an Outlook Add-In, then it fails to even execute the method that contains the connection code, without throwing any exception. This is an extract of the code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAccount, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
NameResolutionCollection coll = service.ResolveName(searchStr, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryThenContacts, true);
```

Anybody has any idea why is this happening? Or if there is another way to search for Global Contacts in Exchange 2013 from an Add-In?

Comment: So what is the actual problem? What do you mean by "it fails to even execute the method"?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, it simply does not execute the routine. before the first line I placed a Mbox dialog and it does not show up. It does nothing. Not to mention, that none of the lines bellow are executed either.

Comment: So when is that code supposed to run? Surely you can step through your code and see why that code is never executed.